# Nested LINQ query

Tags: linq, nested

I'm trying to perform a nested linq query.

```
public class Sic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public List<Sic> Sics { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

List<Message> msgList = new List<Message>();


Message m1 = new Message
            {
                Id = 0,
                Sics = new List<Sic>()
                    {
                        new Sic() {Id = 0, Code = "A2A"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 1, Code = "A2B"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 2, Code = "A2C"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 3, Code = "A2D"}
                    }
            };

Message m2 = new Message
        {
            Id = 1,
            Sics = new List<Sic>()
                    {
                        new Sic() {Id = 4, Code = "B2A"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 5, Code = "B2B"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 6, Code = "B2C"},
                        new Sic() {Id = 7, Code = "B2D"}
                    }
        };

msgList.Add(m1);
msgList.Add(m2);

List<string> searchList = new List<string> {"A2A", "A2B"};
```

I want to find messages in msgList where searchList is contained by the Sics of each each message, i.e. m1 should be found using the above searchList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like,

```
msgList.Where(msg=>msg.Sics.Any(sic=>searchList.Contains(sic.Code)));
```

or if you need to match all search terms,

```
msgList.Where(msg => searchList.All(searchTerm=>msg.Sics.Any(sic=>sic.Code==searchTerm)))
```

Comment: I think OP means "all Ids in searchList" are contained in the Message's Sics.

Answer (score 1):

> > If all ids in searchlist need to be matched

```
msgList.Where(msg => searchList.Any() && searchList.All(s => msg.Sics.Any(sic => s==sic.Code)))
```

> > If any id in searchlist need to be matched

```
msgList.Where(msg=>msg.Sics.Any(sic=>searchList.Contains(sic.Code)));
```